# Ubuntu on VMWare (OS X) doesn't suspend when inactive

Tags: power-management, shutdown, vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm running 13.10 as a virtual machine under VMWare Fusion 6.0.2 on OS X 10.8.5, and also have a Windows 7 VM. My computer is a bit flaky, unfortunately, and occasionally it freezes to the point that I need to do a hard power cycle by pressing the power button until the machine resets. OS X actually recovers surprisingly well from this sort of treatment, unfortunately any VMs that are running do not, even if they are using journalling file systems.

It's kind of a pain, but to get around this I've set up the power management options in Win7 and Ubuntu to shut the VM down after some idle time - 3 or 4 hours in the case of Windows, and 1 hour for Ubuntu. Windows works fine - if I leave the VM running without interacting with it, it suspends itself and so is protected from any power issues.

Unfortunately, I can't get the same behavior with Ubuntu. I've gone to `System Settings -> Power` and set *Suspend when inactive for 1 hour*. After an hour of idle time, the following menu appears:

[image: automatic suspend]

but the VM doesn't actually shut down. What's even stranger is that if I interact with the dialog box in any possible way, nothing happens - I can hit `OK`, `Cancel`, or close it using the `X`, and it just disappears - there's no effect on the system. If I leave the box alone for hours, nothing happens. If I close it then leave the system alone, it reappears, but still has no functionality. I have to manually choose *Suspend*, *Restart...*, or *Shut Down...* from the top menu bar in Unity to actually suspend, restart, or shut down the VM.

I have a pretty vanilla system - it's a new installation of 13.10 x64, not even upgraded from a previous version, and I haven't done any messing around with the system (yet), although if that's what's needed I'm certainly willing and able to.

Is this a known issue, and if so are there any workarounds? Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.